# AWS S3 Bucket -  Add file to inner folder using AWS SDK 

Tags: iphone, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

How can we add a file to an inner folder in a bucket? If there is a bucket named `user` --> i want to add it to the folder `images/selected/` . Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I do to upload a local file (localfilename.txt) to S3 and place files in '[folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571294/how-to-create-folder-on-amazon-s3-using-objective-c)' (image/selected/s3filename.txt).

```
AmazonCredentials * credentials = [[AmazonCredentials alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
putObjectRequest = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"images/selected/s3filename.txt" inBucket:@"user"] autorelease];
[putObjectRequest setFilename:@"localfilename.txt"];
[putObjectRequest setCredentials:credentials];
[[AmazonClientManager s3] putObject:putObjectRequest];
```

Hope this helps. Cheers, Trond

Comment: i will try that [putObjectRequest setFilename:@"localfilename.txt"];
can you explain the line? @Trond Kristiansen

Comment: @xydev The command [putObjectRequest setFilename:@"localfilename.txt"]; just sets the name or path of the local file you want to upload (e.g. /users/test/localfilename.txt). The remote filename and path is set through the command [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"images/selected/s3filename.txt" inBucket:@"user"]