# Migrate to Amazon S3 - Keeping my hierarchical directories?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a Rails 3 app with Paperclip gem.
Actually, my local directories structure is based on my record UUID to stock images:

```
5D5E5641-FCE8-4D0B-A413-A9F993CD0E34
```

becomes:

```
5/D/5/E/5/6/....... 3/4/full/image.jpg
5/D/5/E/5/6/....... 3/4/thumb/image.jpg
```

so that, I never have more than 32000 nodes per directory.

I want to migrate to S3:
1) Can I keep this directories structure on S3 ? Could it be a perf issue ?
2) Does Amazon S3 has its own directories management per bucket ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such stuff as folders in Amazon S3. It is a "flat" file system. The closer you can get to folders is adding prefixes like you said: `5/D/image.jpg` to your file names. In this case, `5` is a prefix and `5/D` is also a prefix. On the other hand, your delimiter could be `/`.

Even though several S3 tools will show you stuff as if they were contained inside folders, this concept does not exist on S3. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329234/amazon-aws-ios-sdk-how-to-list-all-file-names-in-a-folder/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396606/aws-s3-sdk-get-the-folder-instead-of-a-file/) related threads.

You can definitely use the pattern you suggested, and I don't think you will suffer any performance penalties by doing so.

Comment: Someone told me that using a hierarchical structure would even *increase* performance, since under the hood, there is a unix-based filesystem. So, when you use slashes in the file name, S3 actually stores it in a directory with that path. That way, you avoid having a directory with too many files. Is that true?

Comment: @OtavioMacedo I don't think so. There is no reference to this kind of information in their documentation. Also, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394198/max-files-per-directory-in-s3