# Jenkins Continuous Integration with Amazon S3 - Everything is uploading to the root?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, continuous-integration

I'm running Jenkins and I have it successfully working with my GitHub account, but I can't get it working correctly with Amazon S3.

I installed the S3 plugin and when I run a build it successfully uploads to the S3 bucket I specify, but all of the files uploaded end up in the root of the bucket. I have a bunch of folders (such as /css /js and so on), but all of the files in those folders from hithub end up in the root of my S3 account.

Is it possible to get the S3 plugin to upload and retain the folder structure?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible. Instead, I'm using s3cmd to do this. You must first install it on your server, and then in one of the bash scripts within a Jenkins job you can use:

```
s3cmd sync -r -P $WORKSPACE/ s3://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME
```

That will copy all of the files to your S3 account maintaining the folder structure. The -P keeps read permissions for everyone (needed if you're using your bucket as a web server). This is a great solution using the sync feature, because it compares all your local files against the S3 bucket and only copies files that have changed (by comparing file sizes and checksums).

Comment: I would suggest using the JClouds Plug in now.

Comment: JClouds isn't great either; it keeps failing with an obscure error about streaming. Having to fallback to a CLI tool for this is ludicrous...

Comment: s3cmd is not optimal as it requires a separate store for the aws credentials. There's merit to the s3 plugin's use of s3 profiles for authentication. Agree that preserving the artifact hierarchy would be preferable to current behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I have never worked with the S3 plugin for Jenkins (but now that I know it exists, I might give it a try), though, looking at the code, it seems you can only do what you want using a workaround.

Here's what the actual plugin code does (taken from github) --I removed the parts of the code that are not relevant for the sake of readability:

class `hudson.plugins.s3.S3Profile`, method `upload`:

```
final Destination dest = new Destination(bucketName,filePath.getName());
getClient().putObject(dest.bucketName, dest.objectName, filePath.read(), metadata);
```

Now if you take a look into `hudson.FilePath.getName()`'s JavaDoc:

> Gets just the file name portion without directories.

Now, take a look into the `hudson.plugins.s3.Destination`'s constructor:

```
public Destination(final String userBucketName, final String fileName) {

    if (userBucketName == null || fileName == null) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not defined for null parameters: "+userBucketName+","+fileName);

    final String[] bucketNameArray = userBucketName.split("/", 2);
    bucketName = bucketNameArray[0];
    if (bucketNameArray.length > 1) {
        objectName = bucketNameArray[1] + "/" + fileName;
    } else {
        objectName = fileName;
    }
}
```

The `Destination` class JavaDoc says:

> The convention implemented here is that a / in a bucket name is used to construct a structure in the object name.  That is, a put of file.txt to bucket name of "mybucket/v1" will cause the object "v1/file.txt" to be created in the mybucket.

Conclusion: the `filePath.getName()` call strips off any prefix (S3 does not have any directory, but rather prefixes, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329234/amazon-aws-ios-sdk-how-to-list-all-file-names-in-a-folder/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396606/aws-s3-sdk-get-the-folder-instead-of-a-file/) threads for more info) you add to the file. If you really need to put your files into a "folder" (i.e. having a specific prefix that contains a slash (`/`)), I suggest you to add this prefix to the end of your bucket name, as explicited in the `Destination` class JavaDoc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.

It looks like for each folder destination, you'll need a separate instance of the S3 plugin however.

"Source" is the file you're uploading.

"Destination bucket" is where you place your path.

Comment: It's not entirely recursive, but you can upload to a subdirectory within the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jenkins 1.532.2 and S3 Publisher Plug-In 0.5, the UI configure Job screen rejects additional S3 publish entries.  There would also be a significant maintenance benefit to us if the plugin recreated the workspace directory structure as we'll have many directories to create.

Comment: that plugin is not worse trying! it is ok for one file upload but it does not keep directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up your git plugin.

[image]

2. Set up your Bash script

[image]

3. All in your folder marked as "*" will go to bucket