# Check folder size at amazon S3 in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to send files to S3, and i want to know how much space each user is consuming.

For each user i have a folder user/:id/files/.

I can register in my database how much space costs each file when i save it, but i prefere to check it directly at S3, there is an easy way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this counts as easy and mind you I am doing this from the docs but...

Paperclip uses the aws-sdk so if you use it directly like this:

```
size = 0

AWS::S3::Bucket.objects.each do |object| #object should be an S3Object
  if object.metadata(name) =~ /user//:id//files/
    size += object.content_length #in bytes
  end
end
```

You should wind up with the total bytes used by each user. The only thing I am unsure on is the format of the `name` metadata for the object/file. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932892/amazon-s3-folders-problem) the name should have the `/user/:id/files/` format but I am not sure how the other items (e.g. `user`) figure in to it.

You can probably improve on that when you dig in a bit but I think the general idea is there.

I got this from these links:

[AWSRubySDK](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html)

[Bucket](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/Bucket.html)

[Bucket.objects](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/Bucket.html#objects-instance_method)

[S3Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html)

[S3Object.metadata](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#metadata-instance_method)

[S3Object.metadata(name)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/ObjectMetadata.html)

[S3Object.content_length](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#content_length-instance_method)

Comment: You can do this faster by this: 
    AWS::S3::Bucket.objects.with_prefix('/user//:id//files/').do

Comment: Brilliant. +1 for explaining rather than just throwing out a solution, and +2 for the reference links.

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of @ScottJShea's answer, you can use the `with_prefix(prefix)`-method:

```
size = 0
AWS::S3::Bucket.objects.with_prefix('/user//:id//files/').each do |s3_object|
  size += s3_object.content_length
end
```

or:

```
AWS::S3::Bucket.objects.with_prefix('/user//:id//files/').inject(0) { 
  |sum, s3_object| sum + s3_object.content_length 
}
```

Also:

If you are iterating through objects that might be deleted, you will see an exception, you can rescue it like this:

```
AWS::S3::Bucket.objects.with_prefix('/user//:id//files/').inject(0) { 
  |sum, s3_object| sum + (s3_object.content_length rescue 0)
}
```